# Platform specific testing using Jest on a React Native app

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

This is the react native component

```
//Test.js

export default class Test extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                </Animated.View> {
                  Platform.OS === 'android' &&
                  <TouchableNativeFeedback>
                    // some android specific code
                  </TouchableNativeFeedback>
                }</Animated.View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

THis is the test case;

```
//testcases.js
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, Platform } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Test from '../Test'

describe('Testing an App', () => {
    let snapshot;

    beforeAll(() => {
        snapshot = shallow(<Test />);
        Platform.OS = 'android';
    });
    it(' -- must return 1', () => {      
      expect(snapshot.find('TouchableNativeFeedback').length).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

While the expected return is 1; The received value is 0; I have set up Platform as 'android' and yet no luck.

I am new to Mobile automation testing; Hence I could be missing something obvious. Should I use react-dom to render and test further?

I feel it's something very obvious, but can't get my finger on it.

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "exampleApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.42.3"  
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "2.0.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "enzyme" : "2.8.0",
    "react-dom": "15.4.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils":"15.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not change your platform directly in your test. You need to set the desired platform in your settings. Take a look at [this documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react-native.html#providesmodule) to see how to do it.

Comment: During to various version conflict; I had to downgrade react to 15.4.1..
As per this page https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1840
there is no haste support for 15.4.1;

Any version besides 15.4.1 causes haywire.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I dont know any other way of doing it. Sorry, I can't help you with this.

Comment: Its ok. I will find some other way. Thanks for the time.